# NPOI/POI C#/java Скопировать строку, затем вставить её между строк

Tags: java, c#, .net, poi

Возникла задача заполнить один шаблон, в котором 6 шапок списков, эти списки нужно заполнить. Необходимо вставить скопировать, затем вставить между строк строки по 1шт.

```
  #region Вставляю строки 
        for (int i = 0; i < _newList.Count; i++)
        {
            //if(i>0)
            //{
            //    //var row = sheet.CopyRow(10, i + _iterator);

            //}
            /*Заполняю 10 строку*/
            sheet.GetRow(10).Cells[6].SetCellValue(_newList[i].<поле 

            if (i+_iterator > sheet.LastRowNum)
            {
                sheet.CreateRow(i + _iterator);
            }
            _iterator++;
            sheet.CopyRow(10, i + _iterator);
        }
        #endregion
```

Есть функция встроенная в NPOI, которая как раз копирует и вставляет между строк. Но она выдает ошибку в духе

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in NPOI.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Ругается здесь на то что cellRangeAddress возвращает Null:

```
        // If there are are any merged regions in the source row, copy to new row
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.NumMergedRegions; i++)
        {
            CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = sheet.GetMergedRegion(i);
                if (cellRangeAddress.FirstRow == sourceRow.RowNum)
                {
                    CellRangeAddress newCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(newRow.RowNum,
                              (newRow.RowNum +
                                         (cellRangeAddress.LastRow - cellRangeAddress.FirstRow
                                                    )),
                              cellRangeAddress.FirstColumn,
                              cellRangeAddress.LastColumn);
                    sheet.AddMergedRegion(newCellRangeAddress);
                }
            }
```

Comment: А Java тут причём?

Comment: NPOI это перенесенный фреймворк с Java, может там есть решение, я бы перевел его на C#

Comment: ну так у вас где-то Null Pointer, может стоит проверить cellRangeAddress? Может  sheet.GetMergedRegion(i); вернул null?